# Algorithm's that has the run complexity which contains irrational exponents

Tags: time-complexity, logarithm, exponential

Hi I was wondering if there are any algorithms which has the run complexity which contain an irrational exponent. Strassen's algorithm for matrix multiplication is something I am looking for but is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small list with some examples:

- Some algorithms in computational number theory have their complexities expressed in [L-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-notation), and some of them feature irrational exponents: [Lenstra's elliptic-curve factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization#Algorithm), [Dixon's factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_factorization_method#Optimizations), [Index calculus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm#Complexity).
- [Stooge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort) has in its complexity the exponent `log(3)/log(3/2)` which is an irrational number.
- [Toom-Cook multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication).
- Allegedly, [all SAT solvers feature](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/32633) an irrational exponent in their complexity
- [The following list](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/15002)

But more generally, it should be possible to mine (and maybe even monitor) [wikipedia's list of algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_algorithms) , parse and extract the mathematical expression associated with time complexity, and possibly feed the list of expressions into a [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) (for example [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/) using a convertor like [latex2sympy](https://github.com/augustt198/latex2sympy)) capable of figuring out if there are any irrational exponents involved (wikidata could be a better option if it had complete structured data coverage, example: [wikidata's quicksort page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q486598)). It would also be possible to extend this data collection past Wikipedia, into arXiv which apparently [offers latex sources](https://arxiv.org/help/view) for some of the articles, and then employ a latex parser and an expression parser to find these types of complexities.

Comment: Hi, for the stooge sort, do you know when it was invented? Thank you!